# Performance MySQL query with for loop

Tags: mysql, performance, php, date

In this method, first I have to get sundays dates between two dates, in this case about 1 year. Then I go through the dates in a for loop and set them to the query. I use `prepared statements` to make it faster.

```
//Get the first day and last day
$dateInitial = strtotime('2018-08-21');
$dateFinal   = strtotime('2019-08-21');
$final       = array();

$sql = "SELECT id_product, product, plant_sowing, plant_production, area_planting, CONCAT(id_product,'_', weeks) AS identity
              FROM (
                    SELECT sw_sowing.id_product, pr_products.product, sw_sowing.type, YEARWEEK(:dates,3) AS weeks, SUM(sw_sowing.quantity) AS plant_sowing,
                           SUM(IF(ROUND(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,(6-WEEKDAY(:dates)), :dates), sw_sowing.date)/7)>=sw_sowing.weeks_prod, sw_sowing.quantity,0)) AS plant_production,
                           ((SUM(sw_sowing.quantity))/pr_products.plant_m2) AS area_planting
                    FROM (
                          SELECT MAX(id) AS id
                          FROM sw_sowing
                          WHERE status != 0
                          AND id_tenant = :id_tenant
                          AND date <= :dates
                          AND multiply != 1
                          AND id_product = 1
                          GROUP BY id_production_unit_detail
                    ) AS sw
                    INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
                    INNER JOIN pr_products ON pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product
                    INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = sw_sowing.id_variety
                    WHERE pr_varieties.code != 1
                    GROUP BY sw_sowing.id_product, sw_sowing.type
                    HAVING type NOT IN('ER','PR')
              ) AS s";

$statement    = $this->db->prepare($sql);

//get the sunday dates between two dates and bind the variables
for ($i = $dateInitial; $i <= $dateFinal ; $i = strtotime('+1 day', $i)) {
        if (date('N', $i) == 7){
          $values = [
            ':dates'      => date("Y-m-d", $i),
            ':id_tenant'  => 1
          ];

          $types = [
            ':dates'      => Column::BIND_PARAM_STR,
            ':id_tenant'  => Column::BIND_PARAM_INT
          ];

          $result   = $this->db->executePrepared($statement, $values, $types);
          $final[]  = $result->fetchAll(Phalcon\Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
      }
      return $final;
```

But despite this it is not so fast. The query lasts 10 seconds and I would like it to be faster.

I have also indexed the tables. I would like some opinion on how to best optimize this query or if the way I am doing the query is not adequate.

This is a question that I did before about why I use `GROUP BY` and `MAX(id)`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52209300/get-max-ids-by-group-mysql

Comment: Looping is slow.  Can you do the task without looping?  That is a single (but more complex) `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0):

```
                      SELECT MAX(id) AS id
                      FROM sw_sowing
                      WHERE status != 0
                      AND id_tenant = :id_tenant
                      AND date <= :dates
                      AND multiply != 1
                      AND id_product = 1
```

needs `INDEX(id_tennant, id_product, dates, multiply, id)`

`GROUP BY id_production_unit_detail` does not make sense since you are not doing `SELECT id_production_unit_detail, MAX(ID)` and then using `id_production_unit_detail` in some way.

Eh?  Doing this for each Sunday??  `AND date <= :dates` -- That means you are scanning more and more of the table.  And, if there are no entries in a week, returning the same data sometimes.  There are much better ways to get the data for a given week *withouut* scanning the rest of the data.  And it lends itself better to doing everything at once (instead of looping through Sundays).

I assume these are all the same `type`?

```
SELECT ..., sw_sowing.type, ...
    GROUP BY ..., sw_sowing.type
    HAVING type NOT IN('ER','PR')
```

If so, then it would be more efficient to move the test against `type` into `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`.

(There may be more to improve on.  Do these things, then come back for more abuse/advice.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I did your observations and the query lasts 7 seconds, I need to GROUP BY by id_production_unit_detail, because I need the MAX(id) by id_production_unit_detail and I need to check for every Sunday, because the history of each id_production_unit_detail is saved in the table, for this reason I need to do it that way.

Comment: Hmmm...  I don't understand the intent of the query well enough to figure out where to take the discussion from here.

Answer (score 0):

Only considering the query itself,

Tag query blocks with `QB_n` as follows

```
select /*QB_1*/ s.id_product, s.product, s.plant_sowing, s.plant_production,
s.area_planting, CONCAT(s.id_product, '_', s.weeks) as identity
from (select /*QB_3*/ sw_sowing.id_product, pr_products.product, sw_sowing.type,
YEARWEEK('2022-10-01', 3) as weeks, SUM(sw_sowing.quantity) as plant_sowing,
SUM(if(ROUND(DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 6 - WEEKDAY('2022-10-01'), '2022-10-01'),
sw_sowing.date) / 7) >= sw_sowing.weeks_prod ,sw_sowing.quantity, 0)) as plant_production,
SUM(sw_sowing.quantity) / pr_products.plant_m2 as area_planting
     from (select /*QB_2*/ MAX(s.id) as id
            from sw_sowing as s
            where s.status <> 0 and s.id_tenant = 2 and s.date <= '2022-10-01' and s.multiply <> 1
  and s.id_product = 1
            group by s.id_production_unit_detail) as sw inner join sw_sowing on sw_sowing.id = sw.id
   inner join pr_products on pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product  inner join pr_varieties on pr_varieties.id = sw_sowing.id_variety

     where pr_varieties.code <> 1 and type not in ('ER', 'PR')
     group by sw_sowing.id_product, sw_sowing.type) as s
```

Here are some indexes which may help the query performance.

```
CREATE INDEX PawSQL_IDX1919366792 ON sw_sowing(id_product,id_tenant,id_production_unit_detail);
-- When table sw_sowing(referenced in query block QB_2) serves as a DRIVE table in the join planning, PawSQL_IDX1919366792 can be used to do a index LOOKUP with condition(s.id_tenant = 2 and s.id_product = 1), and SORT AVOIDANCE for (group by s.id_production_unit_detail).
CREATE INDEX PawSQL_IDX0767809739 ON sw_sowing(id,id_product,type);
-- When table sw_sowing(referenced in query block QB_3) serves as a DRIVE table in the join planning, PawSQL_IDX0767809739 can be used to do a index LOOKUP with condition(sw_sowing.id = sw.id), and SORT AVOIDANCE for (group by sw_sowing.id_product, sw_sowing.type).
CREATE INDEX PawSQL_IDX0952698883 ON sw_sowing(id,id_product,id_variety);
-- When table sw_sowing(referenced in query block QB_3) serves as a DRIVEN table in the join planning, PawSQL_IDX0952698883 can be used to do a index LOOKUP with condition(pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product and pr_varieties.id = sw_sowing.id_variety and sw_sowing.id = sw.id).
CREATE INDEX PawSQL_IDX1594274845 ON pr_varieties(id,code);
-- When table pr_varieties(referenced in query block QB_3) serves as a DRIVEN table in the join planning, PawSQL_IDX1594274845 can be used to do a COVERING index LOOKUP with condition(pr_varieties.id = sw_sowing.id_variety), and index PUSH DOWN for condition(pr_varieties.code <> 1).
CREATE INDEX PawSQL_IDX1788126893 ON pr_products(id,product,plant_m2);
-- When table pr_products(referenced in query block QB_3) serves as a DRIVEN table in the join planning, PawSQL_IDX1788126893 can be used to do a COVERING index LOOKUP with condition(pr_products.id = sw_sowing.id_product).
```